# Период повторения дискретов синусоиды

Tags: математика, цос

Дана синусоида с частотой `fsin`, отсчеты которой получаются при дискретизации с частотой `fд`. Как показано на рисунке ниже, с какой-то периодичностью множество значений отсчетов будет повторяться. Задача в том, чтобы найти этот период и соответствующую ей частоту `F`.
[image: Дискретизация синусоиды]
На самом деле этот рисунок напоминает случай наложения частот, когда по полученным отсчетам можно построить новую синусоиду с более низкой частотой, равной `fд-fsin`. Однако сейчас случай общий, то есть частота синусоиды может как удовлетворять теореме Котельникова, так и нет. Пока какую-либо зависимость `F` от `fsin` и `fд` найти не удается. Возможно, что есть какая-то формула, которую я пока не видела.

Comment: Формально N/fд == M/fsin == 1/F, где N и M — наименьшие целые числа, для которых это соотношение выполняется. Дальше все упирается в вопросы точности.

Comment: Периоды не обязательно целые.

Comment: А я что написал? *Дальше все упирается в вопросы точности.* Если у вас отношение частот рационально, точное решение есть. Если иррационально — то точного решения нет и быть не может. Только приближение. В принципе, насколько я помню, наилучшее приближение дают цепные дроби, но вопрос только в необходимой точности.

Comment: Можно ли тогда полагать, что M/N - это сокращение дроби fsin/fd? Пока у меня всё сходится.

Comment: Да, но с учетом точности :) Представим, что одна частота - 1, другая - квадратный корень из 2. Точно N/M получить невозможно, но будет масса приближенных с разной степенью точности дробей...

Comment: Спасибо большое!